# Premiere: Renaming cameras in a multi-camera sequence

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

Is it possible to rename cameras in a multi-camera sequence?

Why I need this:
I have a multicam sequence that shows footage that has to be synced with audio for certain people. However it is hard to tell which person's camera it is from what can be seen on the footage. In order to be able to quickly figure out who's view is being shown and what audio to sync with it, it would be nice to be able to rename those cameras to something more descriptive than "camera 1, camera 2, etc ..."

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Multi-Cam sequence, the prompt will give you the option to name the cameras based on the track or clip name.

[image]

I don't believe there is a way to rename the cameras after setting up Multi-Cam.

One other option would be to put each clip into a sequence with a text layer as an overlay. After you have finished arranging your Multi-Cam composition, the text layer can be hidden or deleted.

[image]

Comment: ah cool ... thanks. Should've spent more time in the creation dialogue ... I really hope Adobe will let us do changes like that after the fact some day. Had to do the whole procedure three times because I forgot enable audio switch lol